# convert golang string format of a byte array back into original byte array

Tags: go

So i started with a message as a string, turned it into a byte array and printed it, I've now lost the original string but have the string output of the byte array. I want my string back. (don't ask me why i did this or how... I didn't really, this is just for illustration purposes).

Essentially the bit I'm missing is a convenient way to turn the printed representation of a byte array back into a byte array.

See the example below to explain better what I'm trying to do (complete 'otherWay' func):

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Zh646Y8Jfe)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // started with originalString and lost it
    originalString := "I'm a string I am!"

    // I have the output of 'oneWay()' in my clipboard, so could paste into code
    golangStringFormatOfByteArray := oneWay(originalString)
    fmt.Println("String as bytes:", golangStringFormatOfByteArray )

    // get original string back
    returnString := otherWay(golangStringFormatOfByteArray )
    fmt.Println("Original String:", returnString )

}

func oneWay(theString string) string {

    theStringAsBytes := []byte(theString)
    golangStringFormatOfByteArray := fmt.Sprintf("%v", theStringAsBytes)

    return golangStringFormatOfByteArray 
}

func otherWay(stringFormat string) string {

    // how do I get the original string back

    return "I want you back"
}
```

Comment: you can just do `string(byteArray)`. String is defined as simply `[]byte`, so that simple conversion should do the trick.

Comment: you mean this: not my original string - https://play.golang.org/p/cw39ai7S5_

Comment: Oh, you actually printed it to the `[34 23 45 56]` format? Why? If you are converting it for debugging or something, don't discard the original.

Comment: You're not converting your string into its corresponding byte slice, you're turning into another string that just happens to be the default go  format for printing a byte slice. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to debug a windows service, written in golang, and I need my string back, converting to string crashes it and I cant get an error out but I can get a print of the bytes, I want to see them as a string to work out whats happening - its all a bit convoluted, hence the simple example

Comment: guys, I do know what I'm doing here - its undoing it I need help with :), I presume they are just integer representations of the bytes, so there must be a way to decode, was hoping for a built in

Comment: You will have to write a parser - ignore the brackets, split on spaces, parse each element into a byte, append it to an array.

Comment: So you just need help to parse the format you've printed? Read the values and store them in a `[]byte`?

Comment: Ah OK, nothing built in to std lib to handle it then? I guess generally not much need to go the other way. Can I parse each directly to a byte, or would I have to go string-> int-> byte -> add to array -  I guess it would have to be int8 as well?

Comment: If you are printing it a certain way for debugging, just print it, but don't overwrite the original value with your debug value.

Comment: If printing raw string is an issue, then consider printing with %q format specifier and recovering original string with https://godoc.org/strconv#Unquote.  An alternative is print with %x and recover original with https://godoc.org/encoding/hex#DecodeString.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Cerise I will give that a go and see if it still bugs out - its very odd, i cant even catch a panic - to capncraig in the real world example, i dont have the original string the byte array im dealing with is the result returned from a remote call. any attempt to convert to string kills the service (not the main app) and I cant get an error out

Comment: part 2: some context if anyone is interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478169/useless-bytes-at-the-start-of-docker-exec-response-why-are-they-there-and-safe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that was a fun exercise, if a little pointless:

```
s := "WAT"

// Output as bytes
b := []byte(s)
bs := fmt.Sprintf("%v", b)

// Read bytes
var bb []byte
for _, ps := range strings.Split(strings.Trim(bs, "[]"), " ") {
    pi,_ := strconv.Atoi(ps)
    bb = append(bb,byte(pi))
}

// Print result
fmt.Printf("%s -> %s -> %s",s,bs,bb)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6cRYVJ7goD

WAT -> [87 65 84] -> WAT