# explain and remove useless bytes at the start of docker exec response

Tags: go

Im running the docker api function:

[func (cli *Client) ContainerExecAttach(ctx context.Context, execID string, config types.ExecConfig) (types.HijackedResponse, error)](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/client/container_exec.go#L38)

When I read the response using the built in bufio reader:

```
line, _, err := resp.Reader.ReadLine()
```

I get no error but if I try to convert the bytes to a string the app crashes - the app in question is a windows service, and i think because of this I'm struggling to get an error out of it.

I have now managed to view the output using (logs to event viewer):

```
logger.Infof("res: %q", line)
```

the output from this is:

> res:
>   "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X{\"updating\":false,\"scanning\":false,\"progress\":0,\"discovering\":false,\"registered\":false}"

Now, I was expecting the json but the funky prefix is most unwelcome, any idea what these bytes are are and why they are there? I'm hoping this will inform my next question; what is the cleanest way to remove them or not receive them in the first place?

I'm currently left trimming the bytes by a fixed length but I think I need to do something more sophisticated. I'm thinking left trim these bytes: `\x01` `\x00` but not sure if I should expect any others

Comment: What is `res`? Is is the same as `line` here?  You need to know what is generating that data in order to be certain of how to process it.

Comment: Is your container configured to be run with a TTY?

Comment: @jimB yes, the same, my bad, fixed in question

Comment: @CharlesDuffy looks like its configured with TTY=false

Comment: BTW, converting bytes to a string should _never_ crash without memory corruption or incorrect use of `unsafe`.

Comment: @jimB Ive never seen it before, but as soon as I hit the string conversion the service bugs out, fixed by removing the prefix bytes

Comment: (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88) X=88=length of the json just trim anything before { is encountered to be safe.

Comment: What *is* the software generating that JSON? If this were being done without the cooperation of the code generating the output, it wouldn't know the length. Which is to say that I'm doubting presently that this is having anything to do with the Golang library you're using.

Comment: good spot - it is generated by a php laravel artisan command, nothing seen when run through the cli, not sure whats going on behind the scenes though

Comment: Show the line of code where the app crashes. Show the panic message.

Comment: Cerise, I cant get a panic out of it, the service just dies, I have tried catching and printing and it never hits the code. but if the line after Readline were stringLine:= string(line) it would die

Comment: I suspect the panic stops the event logging - I guess I could try logging to file and see if that logs the panic, ill give it a go and see if I can get an error I would like to get to the bottom of the crash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP response you are getting back is the Docker stream format as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.32/#operation/ContainerAttach).

You should consider using the [`github.com/docker/docker/pkg/stdcopy.StdCopy`](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/pkg/stdcopy#StdCopy) function to demultiplex the stream into stdout / stderr.

Comment: Thanks Imars, that looks like the answer, Ill have a play today and accept once confirmed